# How do I go about debugging a prepared select statement with variable binding Mysqli in PHP?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have the following, which works:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM SOMETABLE WHERE name='music'";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
```

However, when I try to do it with variable binding, it does not:

```
$item_name = "music";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM SOMETABLE WHERE name='?'";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $item_name);
$stmt->execute();
```

How can I go about figuring out why it doesn't?

Comment: Remove the quotes around the `?` The bind tell the extension what data type it is and that will do anything required to prepare the data for onward transmittion

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: "How to debug" is the right question to ask, and there is a guide linked above. However, in your case it could be a challenge, because even with the error message it will be hard to understand. You need to know beforehand that quotes are not used on placeholders because placeholders are not strings.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I couldn't find any examples online that used prepared statements with strings (every example used integers), I was var_dumping the prepared statement and it looks fine (no way to get the resultant query after the fill-in-the-blank though), and the "error message" was just that my results were null.